# REPL: How can I look up information about a type?

Tags: purescript

Coming from Haskell, I struggle finding an easy way to look up type definitions in Purescript's REPL. In Haskell, I can do the following inside GHCI:

```
-- type class
:info Monad 
-- shortcut
:i Monad
-- concrete types
:i []
:i (->)
 -- type constructors work as well with a minimized output
:i Just
```

```hs
type Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
class Applicative m => Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
  {-# MINIMAL (>>=) #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad (Either e) -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c) => Monad ((,,,) a b c)
  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monad ((,,) a b)
  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

I can't find anything similar in spago. Is there a way to get this information without searching it online, for instance in [Pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=Monad)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the type signatures, use `:type`

```
> :type (1 + _) 
> Int -> Int
```

To display the kind of a type, use `:kind`

```
> :kind Maybe      
> Type -> Type
```

To See all the functions, types, and type classes that a module exports, you can use browse

```
> :browse Data.Maybe

data Maybe a
  = Nothing
  | Just a

fromJust :: forall (a :: Type). Partial => Maybe a -> a
...... 
......
```

For more info, you can refer [this](https://jordanmartinez.github.io/purescript-jordans-reference-site/content/01-Getting-Started/05-The-REPL.html)